# How to delay a JMS message from reaching the queue using Spring JmsTemplate

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate, jboss-messaging

I don't want to block the message consumer with a receiver timeout, because as I understand it this "ties up" a thread in the queue server pool (and we have multiple queues configured). So how can I delay the message from being sent without a custom thread (the work is being performed by an EJB 2 session bean)? If it helps, JBoss Messaging 1.x is the provider.

Comment: You want to delay a message on the *sender* side in order not to (allegedly) block threads on the *queue server* (not on the *receiver*) side, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scheduled delivery is a feature of JBoss Messaging...](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/userguide-1.3.0.GA/html/configuration.html#conf.destination.queue.attributes.scheduledmessagecount)

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
Message msg =
sess.createMessage();  
msg.setLongProperty(JBossMessage.JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_PROP_NAME, now + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2); 
prod.send(msg);
```